# HTTP requests routing

Tags: networking, load-balancing, http

I'm wondering how HTTP sub-requests are routed in my network.

Imagine I have 2 pools of webservers.

My domain *www.mydomain.com* targets pool1 and I have a specific rule that makes *www.mydomain.com/myuri* target pool2.

When requesting for *www.mydomain.com/myuri*, I will get an HTML page served by pool2.

But what about the other ressources of my HTML page ? I mean css files, js files or images relative to my page (*www.mydomain.com/my_image.jpg*) ?

Are they gonna be served by the same pool ? If not, what does it depend on ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You must have some sort of loadbalancer or CDN that is splitting the traffic between the pools.  The answer depends on its configuration.